# Changing X-Axis Values in r

Tags: r, plot, axis

I would like to change the x-axis of a plot in R. Here is my example:

```
plot(cbind(result, result),xlim=c(max(result),min(result)),
     ylim=c(min(result),max(result)), xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=result)

result
## [1] 0.6256767 0.6833695 0.7671350 0.5205373 0.4932262 0.5852338 0.5088692 0.3379572
## [9] 0.3420370 0.3029084 0.4677624 0.4822537 0.3047485 0.3852572 0.3186014 0.2009436
## [17] 0.1882227 0.2090007 0.2654110 0.3334744
```

[image]

I want to have new values on the x-axis from 1 to 20. I tried use `axis(1, at=seq(1, 20))` but it did not work.  What should I do to?

Comment: You explicitly set the limits of your x-axis in your `plot` call. You set them to go from the max to the min of `result`, so roughly to start at 0.76 and go down to 0.18. Then you want to add labels for integers 1 to 20? They "work" just fine, they are just far off the boundary of the plot as you have defined it.

Comment: If what you want is to label the points with 1:20, at whatever x values they occur, then you should use the `at` to specify the where the labels go (maybe `sort(result)`?) and the `labels = 1:20`. See the `?axis` documentation for more details.

Comment: I want the x-axis instead of the value 0.76, ..., 0.20, ..., was used numbering from 1 to 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with minimal changes to your example. Basically, I create a `data.frame` with the observation number. Since the plot puts all observations in decreasing order, I also do that to the newly created `data.frame`. This is what I use in the `axis` call.

```
result <-c(0.6256767,0.6833695,0.7671350,0.5205373,0.4932262,0.5852338,0.5088692,0.3379572,
  0.3420370,0.3029084,0.4677624,0.4822537,0.3047485,0.3852572,0.3186014,0.2009436,
  0.1882227,0.2090007,0.2654110,0.3334744)

result_df <-data.frame(my_order=1:length(result),result=result) #add column with initial observation number
result_df <-result_df[order(result_df$result, decreasing = TRUE),] #decreasing order

plot(cbind(result, result),xlim=c(max(result),min(result)),
     ylim=c(min(result),max(result)), xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=result_df$result,labels=result_df$my_order,cex.axis=0.6)
```

[image]